# smoke&Fire CPU & GPU now getting black box

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

It was working, I finally got it to where i wanted it, then rendered it and the fire was not showing up, then i removed some extra nodes I had put in other then the flame ones needed to be added, then the box went black, and I removed the smoke and added it again, changed the setting to where they needed to be, and still I am getting black box using both the cpu or gpu

[image]

MOdded
add pic, I downloaded what I uploaded, and got it working before I changed the smoke fire settings, should not matter but it is not rendering fire.

cpu or gpu with  partial system.

[image]

Comment: Make sure that your smoke simulation plays through correctly and/or that it is baked. I can't verify your .blend file but your simulation data may be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't plug volume shaders into the surface of the smoke domain.

They should be connected to the volume socket.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Along with @cegaton correct answer, I too have found that after a few tries and it stops showing me the changes I make without having to bake it first, that takes time away from adjusting it until I get the desired results, it is as if the nodes get dirty and worn out, having to delete the Attribute node for flame, and giving it a new one. Then it will start "behaving" again.

I've also learned that this is not a what you see is what you get simulator. After getting it to where I wanted it, I rendered one frame and see it was way too much and had to go back to the drawing board.